# What enclosure should I choose to evaluate the next integral using residues?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I have to solve the next integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ibx}(e^{ia/x}-1)dx$$ where $a,b$ are real parameters.

I can use Jordan´s Theorem to show that as $f(z)=e^{ibz}g(z)$ where $g(z)=(e^{ ia /z}-1)$, then if $z=Re^{i{\theta}}$ then $\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}g(z)=0$

I also know how to calculate $Res_{x=0}e^{ibx}(e^{ia/x}-1)$.

But I don´t know what enclosure to chose to can apply the Cauchy Formula.

I think I have to use someone like this, with the small circle surrounding the 0 but i,m not sure at all. Thanks!

My biggest problem is that I don´t know how to evaluate $\int_{\gamma (\epsilon)} f(z)$ where in ${\gamma (\epsilon)}$ $z=\epsilon e^{i \theta}$, $\theta \in [\pi, 2\pi]$.

https://www.google.es/search?q=e%5E%7B1/z%7D+residue+contour&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=566&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=sVyCVcvYCsf4UI6JgpAE&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgrc=5bbprXh9H4tq7M%253A%3BBimypvNQtQrz1M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fzen.uta.edu%252Fme5332%252Fresidue_int1.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fzen.uta.edu%252Fme5332%252F09.html%3B350%3B201

The integral comes from this, I have to evaluate this density function $$f_t(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! e^{-ipx}(e^{\lambda t (c_p -1)}-e^{-\lambda t})dp=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! e^{-ipx}e^{-\lambda t }(e^{\lambda t c_p }-1)dp$$ where $c_p \equiv \mathbb{E}(e^{ipJ})$ and $J$ is a exponencial random variable. So as $c_p \equiv \mathbb{E}(e^{ipJ})=\int_{0}^\infty e^{ipy}h(y)dy$ where $h(y)=\sigma e^{-\sigma y}$, then $c_p=\frac{\sigma}{\sigma -ip}$ so making $q=\sigma -q$, I obtain that my initial problem is to solve the integral I  have put.

Comment: Unless $a = 0$, the integral diverges. When $x$ approaches $0$ from the side $a$ lies on, $\exp \frac{a}{x}$ grows too fast. Since $\exp \frac{a}{x}$ tends to $0$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from the other side, a principal value integral won't help. Why do you want to evaluate that integral? If we know where from you arrived at that integral, we might be able to help you avoid it.

Comment: Fine, Daniel, I will write all the process in case you can help me :)

Comment: $\lambda, t,$ are real parametres. I odn´t know if it helps you :(

Comment: What I have tried it is to integrate in the enclosure I have put in the link, but I don´t know how to make the integral $\int_{\gamma (\epsilon)} f(z)$. Furthermore you say it is bad, isn´t it?

Comment: But you have an $e^{ipy}h(y)$, so you get $c_p = \dfrac{\sigma}{\sigma-ip}$. It's too late at night now for me to evaluate that integral, but the problem is nicely avoided.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. I am happy that this small mistake changes the things. If you can make me (another day)  an outline with the steps to follow I will be very grateful :)

Comment: Know my problem consits on solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ibx}(e^{ia/x}-1)dx$, but I have the same doubts :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ibx}\bigl(e^{ia/x}-1\bigr)\,dx\tag{$\ast$}$$

for real $a,b$, one uses a contour consisting of two segments on the real axis, $[-R, -\varepsilon]$ and $[\varepsilon,R]$ for $0 < \varepsilon < R$, and two semicircles with centre $0$, one with radius $R$, the other wirh radius $\varepsilon$. The small semicircle is used to avoid the essential singularity of the integrand at $0$ [provided $a \neq 0$, if $a = 0$ the integral is trivially 0]. If $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, the integral exists as an improper Riemann integral, if $a \neq 0$ and $b = 0$, we must take it as a principal value integral. In all cases, we need to compute

$$\lim_{\substack{R\to\infty\\ \varepsilon \to 0}} \Biggl(\int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon} e^{ibx}\bigl(e^{ia/x}-1\bigr)\,dx + \int_\varepsilon^R e^{ibx}\bigl(e^{ia/x}-1\bigr)\,dx\Biggr).$$

We close the contour with the semicircles to apply the residue theorem. We need to choose the semicircles in the right half-plane, however.

For the large semicircle, to use Jordan's lemma, we need $\operatorname{Re} (ibz) = - b\operatorname{Im} z < 0$ in the relevant half-plane. Thus if $b < 0$, we choose the upper half-plane for the large semicircle, and the lower half-plane if $b < 0$. If $b = 0$, Jordan's lemma isn't applicable in either half-plane, but we have $e^{ia/z} - 1 = \frac{ia}{z} + O(\lvert z\rvert^{-2})$ for large $\lvert z\rvert$, so the limit of the integral over the semicircle can still be determined.

For the small semicircle, we want the integrand to remain bounded as $\varepsilon \to 0$, and that means we require

$$0 > \operatorname{Re} \frac{ia}{z} = \frac{a}{\lvert z\rvert^2}\operatorname{Re} (i\overline{z}) = \frac{a}{\lvert z\rvert^2}\operatorname{Im} z,$$

so if $a > 0$, we choose the small semicircle in the lower half-plane, and in the upper if $a < 0$. This ensures that the integrand remains bounded, $\bigl\lvert e^{ibz}\bigl(e^{ia/z}-1\bigr)\bigr\rvert \leqslant 2e^{\lvert b\rvert}$ on the small semicircle for $0 < \varepsilon \leqslant 1$. So the integral over the small semicircle vanishes as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

It remains to see when the singularity is enclosed by the contour. That is the case if the two semicircles lie in different half-planes, which happens if $a$ and $b$ have different sign. Then the integral is $\pm 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\Bigl(e^{ibz}\bigl(e^{ia/z}-1\bigr);0\Bigr)$, the sign being $+$ when $b < 0 < a$, and $-$ when $a < 0 < b$. If $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, both semicircles lie in the same half-plane, and the singularity is not enclosed, so the integral is then $0$.

For $b = 0 \neq a$, we can choose the large semicircle in the upper half-plane, the integral then tends to $-\pi a$ as $R\to \infty$, and we obtain the value $\pi a$ for $(\ast)$ if $a < 0$ and $\pi a + 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\bigl(e^{ia/z};0) = \pi a + 2\pi i (ia) = -\pi a$ if $a > 0$, so either way the value is then $-\pi\lvert a\rvert$.

---

Let's, for completeness, also compute $f_t(x)$. Ignoring the constant factor $e^{-\lambda t}$, we want to compute

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ipx}\biggl(\exp \Bigl(\frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}\Bigr) - 1\biggr)\,dp,$$

where $\kappa = \lambda t\sigma$.

For $\lvert p\rvert$ large, we have

$$\exp \Bigl(\frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}\Bigr) - 1 = \frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip} + O(\lvert p\rvert^{-2}),$$

so by Jordan's lemma

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C_R} e^{-ipx}\biggl(\exp \Bigl(\frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}\Bigr) - 1\biggr)\,dp = 0,$$

where $C_R$ is the semicircle with radius $R$ and centre $0$

- in the upper half-plane, if $x < 0$,
- in the lower half-plane, if $x > 0$.

Thus, since the integrand is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{-i\sigma\}$ and $\sigma > 0$, we obtain

$$e^{\lambda t} f_t(x) = \begin{cases}\qquad\qquad 0 &, x < 0 \\ -i\operatorname{Res}\biggl(e^{-ipx}\exp\Bigl(\frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}\Bigr); -i\sigma\biggr) &, x > 0\end{cases}$$

by the residue theorem. Writing $p + i\sigma = z$ to have a simpler notation, we compute

\begin{align}
e^{-i(z-i\sigma)x}\exp \Bigl(\frac{i\kappa}{z}\Bigr) &= e^{-\sigma x}\biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-ix)^n}{n!}z^n\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(i\kappa)^m}{m!}z^{-m}\biggr)\\
&= e^{-\sigma x}\sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \Biggl(\sum_{n-m = k} \frac{(-ix)^n(i\kappa)^m}{n!m!}z^k\Biggr),
\end{align}

so for the residue we find

$$-i\operatorname{Res}\biggl(e^{-ipx}\exp\Bigl(\frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}\Bigr); -i\sigma\biggr) = e^{-\sigma x} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n\kappa^{n+1}}{n!(n+1)!} = e^{-\sigma x} \sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{x}}\cdot  I_1(2\sqrt{\kappa x}),$$

where $I_1$ is a [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

We have so far ignored $x = 0$. In that case, the integral over the semicircle doesn't tend to $0$, whether we choose the semicircle in the upper or the lower half-plane. But then we can use

$$\exp \Bigl(\frac{i\kappa}{p + i\sigma}\Bigr) - 1 = \frac{i\kappa}{p} + O(\lvert p\rvert^{-2})$$

to see that the integral over the semicircle tends to $-\pi\kappa$. Taking the semicircle in the upper half-plane, the integral over the closed contour is $0$, whence

$$e^{\lambda t} f_t(0) = \frac{\kappa}{2},$$

which, unsurprisingly, is the mean of the left and right limits of $e^{\lambda t}f_t(x)$ at $0$.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thanks for your big effort. It´s clear you have not forgotten 5 of them :)  I have been reading carefully what you have explained and I have two little questions: 1- Why for $|p|$ large we have that $\exp \Bigl(\frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}\Bigr) - 1 = \frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip} + O(\lvert p\rvert^{-2})$. I mean, I don´t understand  why the order 2 and bigger vanishes.

Comment: I neither understand why when $x=0$, then $\exp \Bigl(\frac{i\kappa}{p + i\sigma}\Bigr) - 1 = \frac{i\kappa}{p} + O(\lvert p\rvert^{-2})$. It shouldn´t be $$\exp \Bigl(\frac{i\kappa}{p + i\sigma}\Bigr) - 1 = \frac{i\kappa}{p + i\sigma} + O(\lvert p\rvert^{-2})$$. And in this case when you mention the semicircle, you are talking about the small or the big one?

Comment: Finally, I don´t see clear that as for the small semicircle, like I want the integrand to remain bounded as ε→0, why that means we require to $0 > \operatorname{Re} \frac{ia}{z} = \frac{a}{\lvert z\rvert^2}\operatorname{Re} (i\overline{z}) = \frac{a}{\lvert z\rvert^2}\operatorname{Im} z,$ And why "This ensures that the integrand remains bounded," $\bigl\lvert e^{ibz}\bigl(e^{ia/z}-1\bigr)\bigr\rvert \leqslant 2e^{\lvert b\rvert}$"on the small semicircle for"$0 < \varepsilon \leqslant 1$. "So the integral over the small semicircle vanishes as"$\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: We have $$\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{p+a} = \frac{(p+a) - p}{p(p+a)} = \frac{a}{p(p+a)} \in O(\lvert p\rvert^{-2}),$$ so both asymptotic expansions are equivalent. I took $\frac{i\kappa}{p}$ there because the integral of that over the semicircle is known exactly. In that part, due to $\sigma \neq 0$, we only have one (large) semicircle, since the singularity doesn't lie on the real axis, so we need not move around it.

Comment: I have understood everiyhing else, once again, thanks a lot :)

Comment: We need $\operatorname{Re} \frac{ia}{z} < 0$ since $\lvert e^w\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Re} w}$. So if we have $\operatorname{Re} \frac{ia}{z} \leqslant 0$ on the small semicircle, we have $\lvert e^{ia/z}\rvert \leqslant 1$ there. That gives us $\lvert e^{ia/z} -1 \rvert \leqslant 2$, and we have $\lvert e^{ibz}\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Re} (ibz)} \leqslant e^{\lvert bz\rvert} \leqslant e^{\lvert b\rvert\varepsilon}$ on the small semicircle, so the integrand is overall bounded by $2 e^{\lvert b\rvert}$, provided we have $\varepsilon \leqslant 1$. Then the standard estimate gives us

Comment: $$\biggl\lvert \int_{C_\varepsilon} e^{ibz}\bigl(e^{ia/z}-1\bigr)\,dz\biggr\rvert \leqslant 2e^{\lvert b\rvert} \cdot L(C_\varepsilon) = 2e^{\lvert b\rvert} 2\pi\varepsilon.$$ If we took the other small semicircle, we have the value $e^{\lvert a\rvert/\varepsilon}$ at $z = i\varepsilon\cdot \frac{a}{\lvert a\rvert}$, which grows _fast_ as $\varepsilon\to 0$, so we could not estimate the integral over that semicircle.

Comment: And, concerning the question from your first comment, for $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant 1$, we have $$\lvert e^w-1-w\rvert = \Biggl\lvert \sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{w^m}{m!}\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{\lvert w\rvert^m}{m!} = \lvert w\rvert^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lvert w\rvert^k}{(k+2)!} \leqslant \lvert w\rvert^2 e^{\lvert w\rvert} \leqslant e\cdot \lvert w\rvert^2.$$ So if $\lvert p\rvert$ is so large that $\left\lvert\frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}\right\rvert \leqslant 1$, the error is bounded by $e\left\lvert \frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}\right\rvert^2$, and if we further require

Comment: $\lvert p\rvert \geqslant 2\sigma$, we can bound that by $\frac{4e\lvert\kappa\rvert^2}{\lvert p\rvert^2}$. And the the standard estimate tells us that the integral of the error we make by using $\frac{\kappa}{\sigma - ip}$ is bounded by $\frac{4e\lvert \kappa\rvert^2}{R^2}\cdot 2\pi R = C\cdot R^{-1}$, which tends to $0$ as $R\to \infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25015/discussion-between-edin-91-and-daniel-fischer).